# Combining two tables in a query and creating new columns from that

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having issues with a query that I'm not ENTIRELY sure can be done with the way the database is set up. Basically, I'll be using two different tables in my query, let's say Transactions and Ticket Prices. They look like this (With some sample data):

```
    TRANSACTIONS
  Transation ID | Ticket Quantity | Total Price | Salesperson | Ticket Price ID
       5489              250            250            Jim               8765
       5465              50             150            Jim               1258  
       7898              36             45             Ann               4774


     Ticket Prices
   Ticket Price ID | Quantity | Price | Bundle Name
        8765           1          1         1 ticket, $1   
        4774           12         15        5 tickets, $10
        1258           1          3         1 ticket, $3
```

What I'm aiming for is a report, that breaks down each salesperson's sales by bundle type. The resulting table should be something like this:

```
 Sales Volume/Salesperson
 Name | Bundle A | Bundle B | Bundle C | Total
 Jim     250         0           50      300
 Ann     0           36          0        36
```

I've been searching the web, and it seems the best way of getting it like this is using various subqueries, which works well as far as getting the column titles properly displayed, but it doesn't work as far as the actual numerical totals. It basically combines the data, giving each salesperson a total readout (In this example, both Jim and Ann would have 250 sales in Bundle A, 36 in Bundle B, etc). Is there any way I can write a query that will give me the proper results? Or even something at least close to it? Thanks for any input.

Comment: Is there a 1:1 relationship between "Bundle A" in your results and `Ticket Price ID` in your `TICKET_PRICES` table?  If so, how do you know that `Ticket Price ID` 8765 is "Bundle A"?  What happens if there are more than 3 rows in the `TICKET_PRICES` table?  Do you want more columns in your output?

Comment: Using sql server you could do this using cross apply for calculations and creating columns on the fly, not sure if this is possible in oracle?

Comment: @JustinCave At the moment, I don't have any way of knowing that, I wanted to just get a basic structure in place with "hard coded" values in first. And ideally, yes. I'd like to have as many columns in the output as there are in the different bundles.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PIVOT statement in Oracle to do this. A query might look something like this:

```
WITH pivot_data AS (
          SELECT t.salesperson,p.bundle_name,t.ticket_quantity 
          FROM   ticket_prices p, transactions t
          where t.ticket_price_id = p.ticket_price_id
          )
  SELECT *
  FROM   pivot_data
  PIVOT (
             sum(ticket_quantity)        --<-- pivot_clause
         FOR bundle_name          --<-- pivot_for_clause
      IN  ('1 ticket, $1','5 tickets, $10', '1 ticket, $3' )   --<-- pivot_in_clause
        );
```

which would give you results like this:

[image]

Comment: This seems promising. Would this still work even if I didn't know how many bundles there were, or there names?

Comment: The syntax allows you to specify IN (ANY) or IN(<subquery>), but that seems to only work if you use PIVOT XML instead of PIVOT.  The results from PIVOT XML will be a list of SALESPERSON and a BUNDLE_NAME_XML, not a regular query result as when you use PIVOT.